Security vulnerability with my azure web app email service
Current Challenge: I've developed a NestJS Azure web app that retrieves emails from a company account dedicated to receiving purchase orders. This app uses app registration with app access + mail.read permission. While the current setup retrieves emails successfully, it possesses a security vulnerability. The code can be modified to access any email address within the company. My goal is to restrict app access to a single, designated email account.
Question: Is it possible to limit the mail.read scope to a specific email account using app registration? If not, what alternative approach can be implemented to achieve this security objective?
Explanation: • App registration with app access grants permissions at the tenant level, allowing access to all mailboxes. • Delegated access is not suitable as it requires user login, which we want to avoid. I'm open to suggestions for the best course of action.
